Can I use crimp connectors intended for #14 wire on #18 wire?
The backstory:
I have an old rectangular bathroom light/exhaust fan (Fasco Industries, Model #656). Over the course of 40 years, turning the fan on/off lead to vibrations, causing the wires to rub against their metal enclosure. Finally, the insulation wore off, an arc jumped from the wire to the box, and we had sparks.
I'm trying to salvage the fixture. I'm pretty sure the fixture uses 18-gauge wire, I just need to remove the melted portions, and bridge them with new wire.  I have 14 gauge wire, which (correct me if I'm wrong) should be okay (this will be for a run of probably 1 foot, maximum).
My question is: If I use male/female disconnects designed for 14-16 gauge wire, is it safe to crimp 18 gauge wire to a 14-gauge disconnect?
I'm asking about safety from overloading the wire, not the safety of the wire being properly crimped.

I'm asking about safety from overloading the wire, not the safety of the wire being properly crimped. ... then why are you asking about attaching a connector, instead of asking if you can use #18 wire instead of #14 wire?

@jsotola, because my main concern was whether there was a chance of overloading. I was making an assumption that a well-crimped connection would be fine, but now - based on isherwood's response - it sounds like I should really be taking into-consideration that the disconnect is rated for the wire's gauge - not necessarily because there's a chance of overloading, but because a bad connection could impede the flow of electricity to the fixture.  I understand that now.

Your crimp connector has a specified approved wire size range. Using oversized connectors can result in poor conductivity and loose connections. Look up the specs for your part. If it's 12-16, for example, you may want to use other components or techniques. If it's 14-18, all good.
One common strategy is to bend a section of bare wire back on itself to increase wire diameter before crimping.
